# 14 hour layover in Incheon, how to spend the time?

Tags: layovers, south-korea, icn

In a couple days, I'll be arriving at Incheon International Airport (ICN) at around 5 AM local time, and departing 6:40PM. Will sleep till 10AM - 11AM, leaving me with 7 hours of free time.

What's the best way to get a taste of South Korean culture and life in these hours? I know there is a high-speed train to Seoul which takes 45 minutes both ways, but I'm not so sure yet of going that far from the airport. Then again, I would like to get out of the airport if possible, to see some of Incheon.

What are the best places and destinations to go during these six hours? Is it wiser to stay inside ICN or should I spend sometime exploring the area on foot/train/bus? This is assuming that I will have a secure place to put luggage. I *can* also exchange money for Korean Won.

Comment: Have you checked if your nationality allows you to enter South Korea without a visa? That'll make a big difference to what you can / can't do with the layover!

Comment: Incheon has a very famous Chinatown. You should try the famous Korean/Chinese dish [Jajangmyeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jajangmyeon) - it's not spicy at all, unlike most Korean food. There's enough in Incheon that it in fact has [its own full page at Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Incheon). But 14 hours is definitely enough time to go see a bit of Seoul itself instead. I would recommending focusing on just one part of the city though, and be aware of the afternoon rush hour.

Comment: sounds great  - is that the same as "Jjolmyeon" or is that a different one, hippie?